# How to query all NFts for a given account?

Tags: corda

I'm using both the Accounts and Tokens SDK. After creating a NFT using a flow, I need to list all the NFTs this account has in the backend.

`CreateNFTHouseTokenFlow.kt`

```kotlin
@StartableByRPC
class CreateNFTHouseTokenFlow(
    private val noOfBedRooms: Short,
    private val address: String,
    private val price: Int,
    private val icon: String,
    private val name: String,
    private val holder: PublicKey
) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
  @Suspendable
  @Throws(FlowException::class)
  override fun call() {
    val houseTokenState = HouseTokenState(/* ...arguments */)

    val transactionState = houseTokenState.withNotary(notary)
    subFlow(CreateEvolvableTokens(transactionState))

    val issuedHouseToken = houseTokenState
        .toPointer<HouseTokenState>()
        .issuedBy(ourIdentity)
        .heldBy(AnonymousParty(holder))

    subFlow(IssueTokensFlow(issuedHouseToken))
  }
}
```

Now, in the backend: `Controller.kt`

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/tokens/{user}")
    fun getUserTokens(@PathVariable user: UUID): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return try {
            val criteria = QueryCriteria
                .VaultQueryCriteria()
                .withExternalIds(listOf(user))

            val userNFTs = proxy
                .vaultQueryByCriteria(criteria, NonFungibleToken::class.java)
                .states

            ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
                .body("tokens: $userNFTs")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body("exception: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```

The code above returns an empty array. The problem seems to be related to the criteria. For some reason, Corda cannot combine the `withExternalIds(listOf(user))` method with the `NonFungibleToken::class.java` method. If I remove the criteria, Corda can fetch all `NonFungibleToken` tokens (even those owned by other users).

Answer (score 0):

In order to query a state by an account, your state should have the `participants` list property containing the account you want to query by:

state:

```kotlin
@BelongsToContract(HouseTokenStateContract::class)
data class HouseTokenState(
    override val maintainers: List<Party>,
    override val fractionDigits: Int = 0,
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(),
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>,
    // ... other class properties
) : EvolvableTokenType()
```

now when instantiating the class state:

```kotlin
val houseTokenState= HouseTokenState(
    // ... other properties
    participants = listOf(AnonymousParty(ownerAccountPublicKey), ourIdentity)
)
```

Note that the participants default to the `maintainers` property of the state class (which is the Party running the flow). If you override the `participants` property, you should pass the accounts you want + the `maintainers` members.